# Rails: PG Array type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

I ran across this [article Tagging in Rails 4 using PostgreSQL arrays](http://rny.io/rails/postgresql/2013/07/28/tagging-in-rails-4-using-postgresql-arrays.html) demonstrating the power of array data types in Postgres. It seems like it could be useful in many ways, but I never see anyone use it in Rails. Why is this? Is it solely because it's harder to query than, say, a simple join table?

Comment: Perhaps, because it appeared only in Rails 4.

Comment: You're probably right, I'm just surprised I never hear anyone even talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

it just presented in Rails 4 and not a lot of people heared about it, and most of who heared about it not want to break his comfortable zone and use it as there is many way to simulate it:

```
def array_column= arr
  write_attribute(:array_column, arr.join(','))
 end

def array_column
 read_attribute(:array_column).split(',')
end
```

and here is some articles talk about its usage and no one say it has a drawbacks:
http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-arrays-in-rails-with-postgresql/
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/